# javascript: how to show gifs sequantially, avoiding preload

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gif

I have a webpage where I want to sequentially show five animated gifs; I mean that **gif2** must appear and start animation only when **gif1** has ended his animation. I tried the following code, but it has a strange behavior because on FF and Chrome most times it runs as I want, but sometimes gifs appears sequentially but they animation has already ended. In IE, however, it never runs as I want, it seems there is an image "preloading" feature. The animation tooks around 1 sec. Can you help me? Thank you

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#gif1').css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(100).fadeIn(400);
$('#gif2').css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(500).fadeIn(400);
$('#gif3').css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(400);
$('#gif4').css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(1500).fadeIn(400);
$('#gif5').css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(2000).fadeIn(400);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#gif1').css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(400, function() {
      $('#gif2').css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(5000).fadeIn(400);
   });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/PDR9f/6/)